# Nested Query fetch Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client, graphql-js

[categories name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pMkT.png)

[pic of datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDCmZ.png)

```
import {useState, useEffect,useMemo} from 'react';
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import {GET_CLOTHES} from "./GetClothes.js"
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowForwardIos';
import ArrowBackIosNewIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBackIosNew';


function Clothes() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CLOTHES);
  const [products,setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [index,setIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setProducts(data.categories.products);
      console.dir(data.categories.products);
    }
      },[data]);
  //console.dir(products);

 
/*
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!loading && data){
        setProducts(data);
    }
  }, [loading, data])
*/
if (loading) return 'Loading...'               
if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`


  return <div>
    {
      // Products is actually products
       products?.map((product,index) => {
        if (product.name === 'clothes') { //filter 
          // Iterate through products.products to obtain the product data.
          const {name,brand,description,gallery,category} = product;
           return <p>{name}</p>
         }})
       } 
  </div>
}

export default Clothes;
```

`

[image: console.log]

Hello everyone, I am trying to fetch my datas from graphlq however I can fetch to first data from array but when I try reach one of the nested array I got undefined.
How I can solve this issue.

Comment: We don't know how your data looks like. But I guess `categories` is an array

Comment: Yes it is. Now I am uploading image

Comment: `data.categories[0].products`

Comment: thank you now I can see on console.log but still not show up on web page

Comment: I don't see any product with name `clothes`

Comment: I attached to picture of datas for name. It's coming under the categories

Comment: So why do you check `product.name`?

Comment: Because each item category has a name according to their categories. So name is under the "clothes" also.      {__typename: 'Product', name: 'Nike Air Huarache Le', brand: 'Nike x Stussy', attributes: Array(1), gallery: Array(5),

Comment: Try logging the data object itself instead of `data.categories.products`

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to keep `data` as a state variable
2. `data` will be undefined until `loading` is false. The first pass through your `console.log` it will be undefined.

A typical pattern might be:

```
function Clothes() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CLOTHES);
  if (data) {
    … render the data
  } else if (error) {
    …handle the error
    return <Error /> // return an error component
  } else return <Loading /> // return a spinner or other progress indicator
}
```

Note that your function must return a jsx component - it cannot return a string.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First of all, `categories` is an array, so `products` isn't defined as a property in the array. Its items do have the `products` property.

Second of all, `products` is a derived state. You do not need make a separate it as its own `useState`

```
import {useState, useEffect,useMemo} from 'react';
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import {GET_CLOTHES} from "./GetClothes.js"
import ArrowForwardIosIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowForwardIos';
import ArrowBackIosNewIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBackIosNew';


function Clothes() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CLOTHES);
  const [index,setIndex] = useState(0);

  if (loading) return 'Loading...'               
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`

  return <div>
    {
      data.categories.flatMap(x => x.products).map(product => {
        if (product.name === 'clothes') { //filter 
          // Iterate through products.products to obtain the product data.
          const {name,brand,description,gallery,category} = product;
          return <p>{name}</p>
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })
    } 
  </div>
}

export default Clothes;
```

Comment: It still won't work, because there is not product named `clothes` it's a category

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Oh I realise you're right. OP didn't make what they wanted clear enough. So I'll keep this as a response to what the question looks like it means, still quite instructive if I do say so myself.